# UWP, is it possible to add ResourceDictionary value programmatically?

Tags: xaml, uwp, c++-cx

I'm working on adding complex theme for my app. What I thought is when users changes theme, I load a ResourceDictionary and changes it's children at runtime.
But insert operation always fail, please help me.

Following is what I did:

```
auto newResourceDic = ref new ResourceDictionary();
newResourceDic->Source = ref new Uri("ms-appx:///XAMLPages/test.xaml");
if (newResourceDic->HasKey(L"TitleBarColor"))
{
    newResourceDic->Remove(L"TitleBarColor");  
    //It's a SolidColorBrush, I want to replace this brush to a more complex bitmapbrush
    //For convenience, I use a solidcolorbrush instead
    Windows::UI::Color c;
    c.A = 255;
    c.R = 255;
    c.G = 0;
    c.B = 0;
    testbrush = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::SolidColorBrush(c);

    //HRESULT:0x800F1000 No installed components were detected.
    //WinRT information: Local values are not allowed in resource dictionary with Source set [Line: 0 Position: 0]
    newResourceDic->Insert("TitleBarColor", testbrush);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> UWP, is it possible to add ResourceDictionary value programmatically?

When you update above `newResourceDic`, it will throw  **Local values are not allowed in resource dictionary with Source set** exception, it's by default, if you want to add ResourceDictionary value programmatically. We suggest you add `newResourceDic` into App `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries`. Then update with `App.Current.Resources` like the following

**Xaml**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///TestResouce.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

C# code

```
if (App.Current.Resources.ContainsKey("TitleBarColor"))
{
    App.Current.Resources["TitleBarColor"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    App.Current.Resources.Add("HighTitleBarColor", new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Bisque));

}
```

**C++**

```
if (App::Current->Resources->HasKey(L"TitleBarColor")) {
    App::Current->Resources->Remove(L"TitleBarColor");
    Windows::UI::Color c;
    c.A = 255;
    c.R = 255;
    c.G = 0;
    c.B = 0;
    auto testbrush = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::SolidColorBrush(c);     
    App::Current->Resources->Insert("TitleBarColor", testbrush);
}
```